# rsync ESXI 5.5 out of memory in receive_sums

Tags: vmware-esxi, rsync

I statically compiled the latest rsync (3.1.1) & can successfully execute the command on my ESXI server. I am getting the following error from rsync however:

```
ERROR: out of memory in receive_sums [sender]
rsync error: error allocating core memory buffers (code 22) at util2.c(102) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync: [generator] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

Do you know how I could go about making this work? The command I am using is:

> rsync -vrltH --delete -pgo --stats -S -D --numeric-ids --bwlimit=50 -A
>   -X --exclude-from=/home/files/porchefiles/2014.08.03-08.58.10/exclude --link-dest=/home/files/porchefiles/2014.08.02-21.48.13/tree hq.porchecars.com:/home/
>   /home/files/porchefiles/2014.08.03-08.58.10/tree

Both sender & receiver are on 3.1.1.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to copy/move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like something you should be rsyncing to/from an ESXi host. VMware is NOT a general-purpose operating system and the use of `rsync` is not supported. Hence the fact that you had to compile a static version of the utility.

Can you find another approach to move/copy the data you have? If this is for backups, you really should be using something with a VMware API or a purpose-built utility.

Also see: [Why don't people just use rsync to back up vmware guests?](https://serverfault.com/questions/607962/why-dont-people-just-use-rsync-to-back-up-vmware-guests)

Comment: Ok I hear you. So how about I use ghettoVCB to store the backups on a btrfs client which dedupes on completion & then sends the fs differences to the backup server? Crazy or reasonable?

Comment: I actually recompiled the rsync static binary using 3.1.1 and got rid of this error (I had it on 3.1.0) and tried to use it on an ESXi server the way you suggest (ghettoVCB with 2 copies for each VM). Synchronization of ~620GB takes 18 hours, even if the copies do not change name (directories are VMName-0 and VMName-1, only rotated) and the files do not change much. Actual effect is like I just copied the files everyday.